# Crash on launch, error with SKphysics Joint

Tags: sprite-kit, nodes, game-physics, skphysicsbody

I am creating a game and i am trying to create a character that has 2 different nodes, the legs and the torso. I tried to link them using a fixed type joint, however when i do that the torso slides off of the legs sometimes while moving around. Now i am trying to create the character using a distance limit between the 2 nodes hoping that they won't slide away from each other now,however it keeps crashing on launch any ideas? 
here is my code

```
func CreateHero (){

    soldierLegs.position = CGPoint(x: 405 , y: 139)
    soldierLegs.zPosition = 1
    soldierLegs.anchorPoint.x = 0.6
    soldierLegs.anchorPoint.y = 0.7

    let soldierLegsBody:SKPhysicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: 
    soldierLegs.size)
    soldierLegsBody.dynamic = true
    soldierLegsBody.affectedByGravity = true
    soldierLegsBody.allowsRotation = false
    //body.restitution = 0.4
    soldierLegsBody.categoryBitMask = BodyType.soldierL.rawValue
    soldierLegsBody.contactTestBitMask = BodyType.enemy1.rawValue | 
    BodyType.enemy2.rawValue | BodyType.enemy3.rawValue  | 
    BodyType.desertForegroundCase.rawValue
    soldierLegs.physicsBody = soldierLegsBody

    soldierTorso.position = soldierLegs.position
    soldierTorso.zPosition = 2
    soldierTorso.anchorPoint.x = 0.25
    soldierTorso.anchorPoint.y = 0.1

    let soldierTorsoBody:SKPhysicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: 
    soldierTorso.size)
    soldierTorsoBody.dynamic = true
    soldierTorsoBody.affectedByGravity = true
    soldierTorsoBody.allowsRotation = false
    soldierTorsoBody.categoryBitMask = BodyType.soldierT.rawValue
    soldierTorsoBody.contactTestBitMask = BodyType.enemy1.rawValue | 
    BodyType.enemy2.rawValue | BodyType.enemy3.rawValue  | 
    BodyType.desertForegroundCase.rawValue
    soldierTorso.physicsBody = soldierTorsoBody

    let Joint = 
    SKPhysicsJointLimit.jointWithBodyA(soldierLegs.physicsBody!, bodyB: 
    soldierTorso.physicsBody!, anchorA: soldierLegs.position, anchorB: 
    soldierTorso.position)

    Joint.maxLength = 0.01

    self.addChild(soldierTorso)
    self.addChild(soldierLegs)
    self.physicsWorld.addJoint(Joint)

}
```

[image]

[image: What i am talking about]

Answer (score 0):

According to the Apple [official document](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skphysicsjointlimit/1520402-jointwithbodya?language=objc) :

Creating a Limit Joint

```
class func joint(withBodyA: SKPhysicsBody, bodyB: SKPhysicsBody, anchorA: CGPoint, anchorB: CGPoint)
```

Creates a new limit joint.

**anchorA** 
A connection point on the first body in the scene’s coordinate system.

**anchorB**
A connection point on the second body in the scene’s coordinate system.

In your case anchorA is equal to anchorB (the same point), there is no limit, this one cause the crash.

Comment: How do i create a joint limit? i thought setting the joint.maxLength value set a distance limit. How do you suggest i create the limit? @alessandro

Comment: Don't give the same points, give a different points and give a reasonable distance between A and B so they don't overlap each other. You can turn on  skView.showsPhysics so you can see the distance needed..